# Pass multi part message to orchestration

Tags: biztalk

Hi BT Gurus out there!

I am struggling to pass a populated multi-part message from one orchestration to the other. Things I have tried:

- Use 'Call orchestration' shape and pass the message as parameter (RuntimeInternalErrorException)
- Post the message to MessageBox (Direct binding) and then pick it up by the other orchestration, which is subscribed to a message with that multi-part schema (Cannot find part with Index 2. Number of parts in this message is 1. Ensure that you are using custom pipeline that decodes MIME messages if you are expecting Multi-part message.) - How can I use a custom pipeline with Direct binding though?
- Post the message to MSMQ and bind the second orchestration to have a Receive port listening on that MSMQ ( "Failed to decode the S/MIME message. The S/MIME message may not be valid.")

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having in the second bullet: has to do with creating your multipart message in the correct order. You must create the parts for both Multipart message in the same order.

Example:

```
Orch A.
1. Header
2. Body
3. Footer

Orch B.
1. Body
2. Header
3. Footer
```

Biztalk will match the types like so:

```
Orch A.   --> Orch B   
1. Header --> Body
2. Body   --> Header
3. Footer --> Footer
```

This causes the error you received.

[Try This Site for a better explanation for using the Start Orchestration Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577574.aspx)